# EXCHANGE IMAP JAVA SORT

Tags: sorting, imap, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

we are getting mail from ms exchange on imap by using java mail

all is fine if  no one touch nothing ...but if users in outlook move a mail fron another directory in the inbox directory,this become the new top mail insted of its real arrival date could be years ago

as a workaround we are tryng to get the emails already sorted by exchange (normally we get the email in their creation message id order but message id of a just moved old mail is newer than the message id of a just arrived email)

we are using this code to try

SortTerm std[]={SortTerm.DATE};

```
    try {
        messages = folder.getSortedMessages(std);   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }
```

but we get

javax.mail.MessagingException: SORT not supported;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: SORT not supported

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance
regards

stefano buttarelli

Comment: Does the INTERNALDATE of the message get reset?  You should sort by INTERNALDATE if not (not ID/UID), or the Date: header if it does get reset.

Comment: Hi max and thank you for the answer.
we don 't have INTERNALDATE for sorting, here are all we have to sort:
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm ARRIVAL
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm CC
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm DATE
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm FROM
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm REVERSE
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm SIZE
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm SUBJECT
  public static final com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm TO
may be i did not undestand what you did mean ? bye

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Exchange doesn't support the IMAP SORT extension.  You may have to sort the messages in the client.

(Note that the natural order of the mailbox is the order in which messages were added to the mailbox, which is usually the arrival order, except in cases like you're seeing.)

Comment: Thank you for the response, we actually sort in the client but this goes wrong in the case above. We can not get all the messages in the folder inbox order them and then show the first 30 (sorry i did forgot to say that we are developing a web mail client), it should be very slow.
So we get the last 30 messages and sort just them but if the user move an old email in the inbox folder from another folder that will have a newer id and we will get it in the first 30 even if it is very old.
stefano

Comment: Well, obviously you're not doing the sort properly if you're not considering all the messages!  :-)  Yes, that's more expensive in the client, which is why the IMAP SORT extension was invented.  Too bad Exchange doesn't support it.